# Merging a list of data frames and removing NA with na.omit(do.call(merge, x))

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes that are returned from a defined function that look like:

```
[[1]]
NA

[[2]]
            JPY.CLOSE JPY.CLOSE.1      EMA
2017-02-23 -0.5150519   -1.962526 44.07448
```

And to rectify this, I used the code:

```
na.omit(do.call(merge, ret))
```

To try and return something like:

```
             JPY.LAST   JPY.LAST.1      EMA   GBP.LAST GBP.LAST.1    EMA.1  CHF.OPEN
2017-02-09 -0.6968559  0.3526983 44.68176 -0.1920461   1.027927 52.27664 0.5066387
           CHF.OPEN.1    EMA.2 PLN.CLOSE PLN.CLOSE.1    EMA.3 TRY.CLOSE TRY.CLOSE.1
2017-02-09 -0.7241689 52.56533 0.2824105   -1.569392 48.24069 -2.315328  -0.2501765
```

Which I later changed into a matrix such that:

```
 Dates       Currency  %20 MA        %50MA     RSI
2017-02-23   JPY       -0.6968559  0.3526983 44.68176 
2017-02-15   GBP       0.1920461   1.027927 52.27664
```

using the code:

```
out.trend <- matrix(new.trend(MergedData), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(paste0(cursig), c("% dev from 20MA", "% dev from 20MA", "RSI")))
```

However, after making some required changes to my initial data, I'm now getting the error Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must match numbers of columns. I've been stuck for quite a bit, and help would be much appreciated!

Edit: More background information as requested. The above list is returned from this function:

```
new.trend <- function(MergedData)
{
  ret <- as.list(rep(NA,length(MergedData))) 
  ma.sig <- ma.crossover(MergedData)
  pricebreak <- price.channel(MergedData)
  sig <- intersect(which((ma.sig[1,])==1), which(!pricebreak[1,]==0))
  cursig <- character() #Preparing to save currency variables
  for (i in sig) { #Calculates output variables based on active signals
    x <- MergedData[[i]]
    x <- xts(x[,-1], order.by=x[,1])
    dev20 <- (x[,4]-x[,5])/x[,4]*100
    dev50 <- (x[,4]-x[,6])/x[,4]*100
    RSI <- RSI(x[,4], n=14)
    cursig <- c(cursig, cur[i])
    ret[[i]]<- (na.omit(merge(tail(dev20, n=1L), tail(dev50, n=1L), tail(RSI, n=1L))))
  }
  ret[!is.na(ret)]
  na.omit(do.call(merge, ret))


}
print(new.trend(MergedData))
```

The data (dput below) is first organized with

```
cur<-c('EUR', 'JPY', 'GBP', 'CHF', 'AUD', 'CAD', 'NZD', 'SEK', 'NOK', 'CZK', 'HUF', 'ILS', 
       'PLN', 'RUB', 'TRY', 'ZAR', 'BRL', 'CLP', 'COP', 'MXN', 'PEN', 'CNY', 'IDR', 'INR', 
       'KRW')

#Extracts the index of columns that corresponds to each variable
ii = sapply(cur, function(y) grep(paste0("^", y), names(dat)))
MergedData = lapply(as.data.frame(ii), function(x) dat[x])
```

And using this sample dput:

```
structure(list(EUR.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 1409634000, 
1409547600, 1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), EUR.HIGH = c(1.316, 1.3137, 1.3145, 1.3196, 1.3221
), EUR.LOW = c(1.3122, 1.311, 1.3119, 1.3132, 1.316), EUR.OPEN = c(1.3133, 
1.3128, 1.3138, 1.3182, 1.3193), EUR.CLOSE = c(1.315, 1.3133, 
1.3128, 1.3132, 1.3182), EUR.20D = c(1.327, 1.3282, 1.3294, 1.3309, 
1.3323), EUR.50D = c(1.3427, 1.3436, 1.3446, 1.3455, 1.3465), 
    JPY.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 1409634000, 1409547600, 
    1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    JPY.HIGH = c(105.31, 105.21, 104.35, 104.11, 103.92), JPY.LOW = c(104.74, 
    104.3, 104.06, 103.66, 103.56), JPY.OPEN = c(105.09, 104.35, 
    104.08, 103.72, 103.88), JPY.CLOSE = c(104.79, 105.09, 104.35, 
    104.09, 103.72), JPY.20D = c(103.34, 103.21, 103.09, 103, 
    102.92), JPY.50D = c(102.43, 102.37, 102.31, 102.26, 102.22
    ), GBP.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 1409634000, 1409547600, 
    1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    GBP.HIGH = c(1.6497, 1.6615, 1.6644, 1.6614, 1.6614), GBP.LOW = c(1.644, 
    1.6468, 1.6586, 1.6563, 1.6567), GBP.OPEN = c(1.647, 1.6608, 
    1.6593, 1.6586, 1.6576), GBP.CLOSE = c(1.6461, 1.647, 1.6608, 
    1.6598, 1.6586), GBP.20D = c(1.6639, 1.6659, 1.668, 1.6692, 
    1.6703), GBP.50D = c(1.6882, 1.6892, 1.6903, 1.6911, 1.6919
    ), CHF.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 1409634000, 1409547600, 
    1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    CHF.HIGH = c(0.9201, 0.9212, 0.9198, 0.9184, 0.9162), CHF.LOW = c(0.9176, 
    0.9188, 0.9177, 0.9139, 0.9126), CHF.HIGH.1 = c(0.919, 0.9196, 
    0.9179, 0.9151, 0.9148), CHF.OPEN = c(0.9177, 0.919, 0.9196, 
    0.9182, 0.9151), CHF.CLOSE = c(0.9118, 0.9113, 0.9108, 0.9102, 
    0.9096), CHF50D = c(0.9037, 0.9032, 0.9027, 0.9022, 0.9017
    ), AUD.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 1409634000, 1409547600, 
    1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    AUD.HIGH = c(0.9351, 0.9337, 0.9352, 0.9363, 0.9374), AUD.LOW = c(0.9263, 
    0.9268, 0.9319, 0.9332, 0.9332), AUD.OPEN = c(0.9274, 0.9332, 
    0.9329, 0.9357, 0.9337), AUD.CLOSE = c(0.9347, 0.9274, 0.9332, 
    0.9339, 0.9357), AUD.20D = c(0.9307, 0.9308, 0.9309, 0.9309, 
    0.9308), AUD.50D = c(0.9354, 0.9355, 0.9357, 0.9358, 0.9359
    ), CAD.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 1409634000, 1409547600, 
    1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    CAD.HIGH = c(1.0943, 1.0935, 1.0878, 1.0879, 1.0869), CAD.LOW = c(1.0871, 
    1.0867, 1.0857, 1.0811, 1.0837), CAD.OPEN = c(1.0929, 1.0871, 
    1.0869, 1.0861, 1.0865), CAD.CLOSE = c(1.0888, 1.0929, 1.0871, 
    1.0878, 1.0861), CAD.20D = c(1.0918, 1.092, 1.0921, 1.0923, 
    1.0925), CAD.50D = c(1.082, 1.0817, 1.0813, 1.081, 1.0808
    ), NZD.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 1409634000, 1409547600, 
    1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    NZD.HIGH = c(0.8332, 0.8391, 0.8389, 0.8398, 0.8408), NZD.LOW = c(0.8288, 
    0.8292, 0.8348, 0.8356, 0.8364), NZD.OPEN = c(0.8316, 0.8377, 
    0.8356, 0.8383, 0.8374), NZD.CLOSE = c(0.8326, 0.8316, 0.8377, 
    0.8362, 0.8383), NZD.20D = c(0.8408, 0.8416, 0.8424, 0.8431, 
    0.8439), NZD.50D = c(0.8568, 0.8576, 0.8583, 0.859, 0.8596
    ), SEK.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 1409634000, 1409547600, 
    1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    SEK.HIGH = c(7.0249, 7.0242, 7.0346, 6.9967, 6.9859), SEK.LOW = c(6.9894, 
    6.9945, 6.9795, 6.943, 6.9279), SEK.CLOSE = c(7.0167, 7.0045, 
    6.9795, 6.9717, 6.9495), SEK.OPEN = c(7.0038, 7.0167, 7.0045, 
    6.9918, 6.9717), SEK.20D = c(6.9201, 6.9146, 6.908, 6.9019, 
    6.8953), SEK.50D = c(6.8588, 6.8534, 6.8476, 6.8414, 6.8358
    ), NOK.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 1409634000, 1409547600, 
    1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    NOK.HIGH = c(6.2314, 6.2054, 6.2094, 6.2021, 6.1938), NOK.LOW = c(6.1855, 
    6.1832, 6.1776, 6.1697, 6.166), NOK.OPEN = c(6.1874, 6.1919, 
    6.1939, 6.1795, 6.1804), NOK.CLOSE = c(6.2179, 6.1874, 6.1919, 
    6.1975, 6.1795), NOK.20D = c(7.5563, 7.5738, 7.5975, 7.5975, 
    7.5975), NOK.50D = c(6.1941, 6.1924, 6.1909, 6.1892, 6.1876
    ), CZK.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 1409634000, 1409547600, 
    1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    CZK.HIGH = c(21.1358, 21.2163, 21.1489, 21.1551, 21.1434), 
    CZK.LOW = c(21.017, 21.1095, 21.0906, 21.013, 20.9375), CZK.OPEN = c(21.1247, 
    21.1359, 21.1065, 21.1101, 20.9924), CZK.CLOSE = c(21.0528, 
    21.1247, 21.1359, 21.1194, 21.11), CZK.20D = c(21.1247, 21.1359, 
    21.1065, 21.1101, 20.9924), CZK.50D = c(21.0528, 21.1247, 
    21.1359, 21.1194, 21.11), HUF.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 
    1409634000, 1409547600, 1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), HUF.HIGH = c(240.5, 240.92, 240.55, 
    240.35, 240.3), HUF.LOW = c(238.35, 239.2, 238.96, 238.51, 
    236.56), HUF.HIGH.1 = c(240.31, 239.49, 240.09, 239.06, 237
    ), HUF.LOW.1 = c(238.76, 240.31, 239.49, 239.77, 239.06), 
    HUF.20D = c(236.55, 236.41, 236.2, 235.9, 235.57), HUF.50D = c(232.32, 
    232.05, 231.74, 231.44, 231.14), ILS.DATE = structure(c(1409115600, 
    1409029200, 1408942800, 1408683600, 1408597200), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), ILS.HIGH = c(3.576, 3.588, 3.5775, 
    3.543, 3.5505), ILS.LOW = c(3.5615, 3.563, 3.534, 3.514, 
    3.5185), ILS.HIGH.1 = c(3.5703, 3.579, 3.5345, 3.525, 3.545
    ), ILS.LOW.1 = c(3.563, 3.57, 3.5705, 3.533, 3.526), ILS.20D = c(3.4915, 
    3.4849, 3.4779, 3.4707, 3.4654), ILS.50D = c(3.4526, 3.4503, 
    3.4481, 3.4458, 3.4442), PLN.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 
    1409634000, 1409547600, 1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), PLN.HIGH = c(3.2095, 3.2148, 3.213, 
    3.2164, 3.2101), PLN.LOW = c(3.182, 3.2005, 3.2003, 3.193, 
    3.1767), PLN.HIGH.1 = c(3.2058, 3.2017, 3.2089, 3.2036, 3.1831
    ), PLN.LOW.1 = c(3.1909, 3.2058, 3.2017, 3.2056, 3.2036), 
    PLN.20D = c(3.1628, 3.1603, 3.1565, 3.152, 3.1475), PLN.50D = c(3.1061, 
    3.103, 3.1, 3.0971, 3.0943), RUB.DATE = structure(c(1406696400, 
    1406610000, 1406523600, 1406264400, 1406178000), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), RUB.HIGH = c(35.9303, 35.758, 35.56, 
    35.1373, 35.1463), RUB.LOW = c(35.4986, 35.5684, 35.2557, 
    35.0105, 34.9402), RUB.HIGH.1 = c(35.9106, 35.6705, 35.2578, 
    35.0906, 35.0165), RUB.LOW.1 = c(35.614, 35.6753, 35.5252, 
    35.0817, 35.0413), RUB.20D = c(34.7338, 34.6695, 34.6022, 
    34.5282, 34.4608), RUB.50D = c(34.5266, 34.5052, 34.4821, 
    34.4666, 34.4596), TRY.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 1409634000, 
    1409547600, 1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), TRY.HIGH = c(2.1742, 2.1782, 2.1657, 
    2.1652, 2.1727), TRY.LOW = c(2.1563, 2.1595, 2.1569, 2.1537, 
    2.1536), TRY.LOW.1 = c(2.1725, 2.1602, 2.1619, 2.1581, 2.154
    ), TRY.HIGH.1 = c(2.1572, 2.1727, 2.1603, 2.163, 2.1581), 
    TRY.20D = c(2.1637, 2.1638, 2.1628, 2.1613, 2.1599), TRY.50D = c(2.1392, 
    2.1387, 2.1381, 2.1376, 2.1372), ZAR.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 
    1409634000, 1409547600, 1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), ZAR.HIGH = c(10.748, 10.7486, 10.6852, 
    10.6735, 10.6868), ZAR.LOW = c(10.6707, 10.6713, 10.6448, 
    10.5904, 10.6034), ZAR.HIGH.1 = c(10.7402, 10.6747, 10.6636, 
    10.6511, 10.6129), ZAR.LOW.1 = c(10.6886, 10.7402, 10.6747, 
    10.6666, 10.6511), ZAR.20D = c(10.6601, 10.6608, 10.6616, 
    10.6606, 10.6612), ZAR.50D = c(10.6612, 10.6593, 10.6573, 
    10.6558, 10.6554), BRL.DATE = structure(c(1406869200, 1406782800, 
    1406696400, 1406610000, 1406523600), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), BRL.HIGH = c(2.282, 2.2748, 2.26, 
    2.2321, 2.2348), BRL.LOW = c(2.2508, 2.253, 2.233, 2.224, 
    2.2222), BRL.HIGH.1 = c(2.2723, 2.2551, 2.2366, 2.2276, 2.2294
    ), BRL.LOW.1 = c(2.2573, 2.2638, 2.2456, 2.2315, 2.2225), 
    BRL.20D = c(2.2279, 2.2261, 2.2234, 2.2224, 2.2209), BRL.50D = c(2.2301, 
    2.2293, 2.2282, 2.2276, 2.2271), CLP.DATE = structure(c(1406091600, 
    1406005200, 1405918800, 1405659600, 1405573200), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), CLP.HIGH = c(568.55, 568.55, 568.55, 
    568.56, 565.75), CLP.LOW = c(562.82, 562.16, 559.45, 564.55, 
    557.75), CLP.HIGH.1 = c(564.51, 563.91, 568.55, 564.8, 559.51
    ), CLP.LOW.1 = c(563.57, 564.65, 564.57, 567.61, 564.54), 
    CLP.20D = c(555.58, 554.99, 554.39, 553.96, 553.43), CLP.50D = c(554.1, 
    553.87, 553.69, 553.47, 553.42), COP.DATE = structure(c(1406264400, 
    1406178000, 1406091600, 1406005200, 1405918800), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), COP.HIGH = c(1849.5, 1847.5, 1847.7, 
    1856.5, 1868.5), COP.LOW = c(1846.5, 1842.76, 1845.5, 1856.5, 
    1866.7), COP.OPEN = c(1847.7, 1842.76, 1847.7, 1856.5, 1866.7
    ), COP.CLOSE = c(1849.5, 1846.5, 1846.5, 1856.5, 1868.5), 
    COP.20D = c(1860.69, 1862.74, 1864.64, 1866.49, 1867.79), 
    COP.50D = c(1884.4, 1885.48, 1886.76, 1888.04, 1889.27), 
    MXN.DATE = structure(c(1409720400, 1409634000, 1409547600, 
    1409288400, 1409202000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    MXN.HIGH = c(13.1196, 13.1476, 13.0999, 13.1009, 13.1309), 
    MXN.LOW = c(13.0732, 13.0912, 13.0575, 13.0464, 13.0689), 
    MXN.HIGH.1 = c(13.109, 13.0959, 13.0633, 13.0856, 13.0844
    ), MXN.LOW.1 = c(13.0986, 13.109, 13.0959, 13.0847, 13.0856
    ), MXN.20D = c(13.1203, 13.1271, 13.1363, 13.1413, 13.1462
    ), MXN.50D = c(13.0609, 13.059, 13.058, 13.0567, 13.0548), 
    PEN.DATE = structure(c(1407214800, 1407128400, 1406869200, 
    1406782800, 1406696400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    PEN.HIGH = c(2.816, 2.8091, 2.799, 2.802, 2.7935), PEN.LOW = c(2.8089, 
    2.7973, 2.795, 2.7926, 2.7866), PEN.LOW.1 = c(2.8128, 2.7983, 
    2.798, 2.793, 2.7873), PEN.HIGH.1 = c(2.8149, 2.808, 2.7982, 
    2.8011, 2.7895), PEN.20D = c(2.79, 2.7881, 2.7862, 2.7851, 
    2.7846), PEN.50D = c(2.7899, 2.7893, 2.7889, 2.7887, 2.7885
    ), CNY.DATE = structure(c(1404277200, 1404190800, 1404104400, 
    1403845200, 1403758800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    CNY.HIGH = c(6.2134, 6.2066, 6.2167, 6.2258, 6.2337), CNY.LOW = c(6.198, 
    6.1973, 6.2, 6.216, 6.2243), CNY.OPEN = c(6.198, 6.2023, 
    6.2166, 6.2258, 6.229), CNY.CLOSE = c(6.2101, 6.2009, 6.2033, 
    6.2179, 6.2248), CNY.20D = c(6.2256, 6.2276, 6.2303, 6.2325, 
    6.2336), CNY.50D = c(6.2344, 6.2347, 6.2351, 6.2354, 6.2355
    ), IDR.DATE = structure(c(1405314000, 1405054800, 1404968400, 
    1404795600, 1404709200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    IDR.HIGH = c(11670, 11637, 11595, 11781, 11870), IDR.LOW = c(11609, 
    11579, 11513, 11605, 11683), IDR.HIGH.1 = c(11610, 11605, 
    11571, 11708, 11829), IDR.LOW.1 = c(11670, 11590, 11580, 
    11630, 11710), IDR.20D = c(11869, 11876, 11886, 11897, 11906
    ), IDR.50D = c(11724, 11722, 11722, 11722, 11722), INR.DATE = structure(c(1402981200, 
    1402894800, 1402635600, 1402549200, 1402462800), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), INR.HIGH = c(60.525, 60.225, 59.8, 
    59.3625, 59.36), INR.LOW = c(60.35, 59.84, 59.3037, 59.325, 
    59.325), INR.HIGH.1 = c(59.1977, 59.1287, 59.0502, 59.0007, 
    59.0025), INR.LOW.1 = c(59.7126, 59.7186, 59.7186, 59.7327, 
    59.7634), X67.7266 = c(62.8711, 62.8345, 62.7951, 62.7951, 
    62.7951), INR.20D = c(1031.35, 1029.65, 1030.57, 1032.55, 
    1041.23), INR.50D = c(1031, 1028.9, 1029.28, 1030.5, 1037
    ), KRW.DATE = structure(c(1407992400, 1407906000, 1407819600, 
    1407733200, 1407474000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    KRW.HIGH = c(1028.77, 1029.18, 1029.31, 1029.35, 1028.73), 
    KRW.LOW = c(1021.92, 1021.91, 1021.78, 1021.72, 1021.58), 
    KRW.HIGH.1 = c(3.205, 3.2137, 3.1978, 3.184, 3.1748), KRW.LOW.1 = c(3.205, 
    3.208, 3.1805, 3.1745, 3.1745), KRW.20D = c(3.1813, 3.1806, 
    3.1793, 3.1793, 3.1805), KRW.50D = c(3.2015, 3.2017, 3.2017, 
    3.202, 3.2027)), .Names = c("EUR.DATE", "EUR.HIGH", "EUR.LOW", 
"EUR.OPEN", "EUR.CLOSE", "EUR.20D", "EUR.50D", "JPY.DATE", "JPY.HIGH", 
"JPY.LOW", "JPY.OPEN", "JPY.CLOSE", "JPY.20D", "JPY.50D", "GBP.DATE", 
"GBP.HIGH", "GBP.LOW", "GBP.OPEN", "GBP.CLOSE", "GBP.20D", "GBP.50D", 
"CHF.DATE", "CHF.HIGH", "CHF.LOW", "CHF.HIGH.1", "CHF.OPEN", 
"CHF.CLOSE", "CHF50D", "AUD.DATE", "AUD.HIGH", "AUD.LOW", "AUD.OPEN", 
"AUD.CLOSE", "AUD.20D", "AUD.50D", "CAD.DATE", "CAD.HIGH", "CAD.LOW", 
"CAD.OPEN", "CAD.CLOSE", "CAD.20D", "CAD.50D", "NZD.DATE", "NZD.HIGH", 
"NZD.LOW", "NZD.OPEN", "NZD.CLOSE", "NZD.20D", "NZD.50D", "SEK.DATE", 
"SEK.HIGH", "SEK.LOW", "SEK.CLOSE", "SEK.OPEN", "SEK.20D", "SEK.50D", 
"NOK.DATE", "NOK.HIGH", "NOK.LOW", "NOK.OPEN", "NOK.CLOSE", "NOK.20D", 
"NOK.50D", "CZK.DATE", "CZK.HIGH", "CZK.LOW", "CZK.OPEN", "CZK.CLOSE", 
"CZK.20D", "CZK.50D", "HUF.DATE", "HUF.HIGH", "HUF.LOW", "HUF.HIGH.1", 
"HUF.LOW.1", "HUF.20D", "HUF.50D", "ILS.DATE", "ILS.HIGH", "ILS.LOW", 
"ILS.HIGH.1", "ILS.LOW.1", "ILS.20D", "ILS.50D", "PLN.DATE", 
"PLN.HIGH", "PLN.LOW", "PLN.HIGH.1", "PLN.LOW.1", "PLN.20D", 
"PLN.50D", "RUB.DATE", "RUB.HIGH", "RUB.LOW", "RUB.HIGH.1", "RUB.LOW.1", 
"RUB.20D", "RUB.50D", "TRY.DATE", "TRY.HIGH", "TRY.LOW", "TRY.LOW.1", 
"TRY.HIGH.1", "TRY.20D", "TRY.50D", "ZAR.DATE", "ZAR.HIGH", "ZAR.LOW", 
"ZAR.HIGH.1", "ZAR.LOW.1", "ZAR.20D", "ZAR.50D", "BRL.DATE", 
"BRL.HIGH", "BRL.LOW", "BRL.HIGH.1", "BRL.LOW.1", "BRL.20D", 
"BRL.50D", "CLP.DATE", "CLP.HIGH", "CLP.LOW", "CLP.HIGH.1", "CLP.LOW.1", 
"CLP.20D", "CLP.50D", "COP.DATE", "COP.HIGH", "COP.LOW", "COP.OPEN", 
"COP.CLOSE", "COP.20D", "COP.50D", "MXN.DATE", "MXN.HIGH", "MXN.LOW", 
"MXN.HIGH.1", "MXN.LOW.1", "MXN.20D", "MXN.50D", "PEN.DATE", 
"PEN.HIGH", "PEN.LOW", "PEN.LOW.1", "PEN.HIGH.1", "PEN.20D", 
"PEN.50D", "CNY.DATE", "CNY.HIGH", "CNY.LOW", "CNY.OPEN", "CNY.CLOSE", 
"CNY.20D", "CNY.50D", "IDR.DATE", "IDR.HIGH", "IDR.LOW", "IDR.HIGH.1", 
"IDR.LOW.1", "IDR.20D", "IDR.50D", "INR.DATE", "INR.HIGH", "INR.LOW", 
"INR.HIGH.1", "INR.LOW.1", "X67.7266", "INR.20D", "INR.50D", 
"KRW.DATE", "KRW.HIGH", "KRW.LOW", "KRW.HIGH.1", "KRW.LOW.1", 
"KRW.20D", "KRW.50D"), row.names = 647:651, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: hi: gonna need the initial data and the changes you made to give any sort of answer.

Comment: as @ike stated a bit more data would be helpful. Also you may try l = l[!sapply(l, is.null)] to remove your lists with NA

Comment: @ike Can't really give initial changes since the data was from Excel. I added in additional columns to Excel. Initial data is attached, along with the codes I used to transform it as well as the code that returns the list in my question.

Comment: @B Williams This worked on removing the NA. I'm now trying to figure a way to condense my list into a table that I want to output via HTML. Edited my question, thanks!

Comment: basically your error looks like the type that pops up if you've got disjointed rows, so you've got 100 in one segment and 200 in the other and r is looking for complete cases; if it runs out then the formula breaks.

Comment: @ike Hmm interesting. I'm guessing it could be that my list is returning some dataframes that are NA. Is there an alternative na.omit(do.call(merge, ret)) that would let me merge the lists containing non-empty dataframes and removes any NA dataframes?